# How to use RECURSION to group items in a list using python

Tags: python, list, recursion, nested-lists

I'm trying to create a function that consumes a flat list and returns a list of lists/nested list that basically groups the values of the original list together based on their value.

so basically

```
L = [ 1, 19, 5, 2, 22, 12 28]
```

if I group them in groups of based on groups of 10 L will become

```
L = [[1, 2, 5], [12, 19], [22, 28]]
```

However I HAVE to use recursion to do this. I'm a little lost and don't know where to start. If I can have a bit of help I would appreciate it

```
def group_lists(L, pos): 
      if pos>=len(L):
        return none 
      else:
        if L[pos]<=10:
          return ?    
        elif 20>=L[pos]>10:
          return ? 
        else: 
          return ?
```

Comment: It doesn't matter much. Sorting is easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the intermediate result through the recursive calls, and then return it when you've run out of elements. If you must use exactly two parameters for whatever reason, make a wrapper function or use the `global` keyword. (I would not recommend using `global` in practice, however.)

```py
def group_lists(L, pos, result): 
  if len(L) <= pos:
    return result
  else:
    result[L[pos] // 10].append(L[pos])
    return group_lists(L, pos + 1, result)
    
L = [ 1, 19, 5, 2, 22, 12, 28]

print(group_lists(L, 0, [[], [], []]))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I just have a question for further clarification. I see you set result as a list of 3 lists but what if we didn't know how many groups there were. Like I want this function to work for a list of numbers of any length and say it goes from 0-90-→  in the case there will be 9 different groups instead of 3.

Comment: Use a `dict[int, list[str]]`, where the key represents the group index (determined by integer division by 10, like in the original)
.

Comment: oh this is useful! thank you so much!

Comment: I also just realized there's an issue in the type I gave you. The values should be `list[int]`, not `list[str]`. Apologies if that caused any confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```py
lst = [1, 19, 5, 2, 22, 12, 28]

def group_lists(lst):
    if not lst: # empty list
        return []
    output = group_lists(lst[1:]) # recursion
    while len(output) <= lst[0] // 10: # if not enough slots
        output.append([]) # make as many as needed
    output[lst[0] // 10].append(lst[0]) # append the item to the right slot
    return output

print(group_lists(lst)) # [[2, 5, 1], [12, 19], [28, 22]]
```

This would automatically add slots as needed, using a `while` loop. It will make empty slots if your input is something like `[1, 21]`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version that adds one sublist per recursive call:

```
>>> def group_lists(arr):
...     if isinstance(arr[-1], list):
...         return arr
...     i = sum(isinstance(sub, list) for sub in arr)
...     return group_lists(
...         arr[:i]
...         + [[n for n in arr[i:] if n // 10 == i]]
...         + [n for n in arr[i:] if n // 10 != i]
...     )
...
>>> group_lists([1, 19, 5, 2, 22, 12, 28])
[[1, 5, 2], [19, 12], [22, 28]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `defaultdict` structure from `collection` module like

```
from collections import defaultdict
def group_list(L, res=defaultdict(list)):
    if len(L) == 1:
        res[L[0] // 10].append(L[0])
        return
    if len(L) == 0:
        return
    group_list(L[:len(L) // 2])
    group_list(L[len(L) // 2:])
    return res

print(group_list([ 1, 19, 5, 2, 22, 12, 28]))

#defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {0: [1, 5, 2], 1: [19, 12], 2: [22, 28]})
```

Comment: thank you, unfortunately we can't use the collection module.

Comment: @OreB then you can change "append-string" to condition ```if L[0] // 10 in res: res.append(L[0]) else: res[L[0] // 10] = [L[0]]```